# How can I get the Range of filtered rows using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, automation, vsto

I'm using Excel Interop assemblies for my project,
if I want to use auto filter with then thats possible using

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1,SheetNames[1],Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,oMissing,false)
```

but how can I get the filtered rows ??

can anyone have idea??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you filtered the range, you can access the cells that pass the filter criteria by making use of the [Range.SpecialCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells(office.11).aspx) method, passing in a valued of 'Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible' in order to get the visible cells.

Based on your example code, above, accessing the visible cells should look something like this:

```
Excel.Range visibleCells = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(
                               Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, 
                               Type.Missing)
```

From there you can either access each cell in the visible range, via the 'Range.Cells' collection, or access each row, by first accessing the areas via the 'Range.Areas' collection and then iterating each row within the 'Rows' collection for each area. For example:

```
foreach (Excel.Range area in visibleCells.Areas)
{
    foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
    {
        // Process each un-filtered, visible row here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Mike

Comment: Can the downvoter explain themselves? This is a clean solution and it did work for the original poster. Is there something that didn't work for you here?

Comment: Agree, one should place comment when giving negative votes to any answer, - so at least any user can update it or provide better solution for the same :)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it doesnt work for me either.  The range returned is only up to the first hidden row.  It doesnt 'jump' any gaps.

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to obtain the value of the visible cells of column E, but it's just cycling through each char of the cell. Do you have any ideas?

`foreach (Excel.Range area in filterValue.Areas)
            {
                foreach (var value in area.Columns[5].Cell.Value)`

Comment: Is it possible to move the whole area at once instead of row by row?

Answer (score 1):

I used as mentioned below, similar to what Mike told,

```
foreach (Excel.Range area in visibleCells.Areas)
{
 foreach(Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
 {
 int index = row.Row; // now index is the present Row index within the range
 string test = Mysheet.Cells[index,4].Values //// Mysheet is my present working sheet. After this test will contain the values pointing to the values.cells[index,4]
 }
}
```