# How do I access a cell in Excel Interop when using filtered ranges?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel, excel-interop

I originally had a code segment that iterated through rows of an Excel spreadsheet using the UsedRange as such:

```
           range = ws.UsedRange;
           for (int row = 3; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                Object nObj = ((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[row, "N"]).Text;
            }
```

But I needed to only get the rows that remained after I applied a filter so (after viewing [How can I get the Range of filtered rows using Excel Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916490/how-can-i-get-the-range-of-filtered-rows-using-excel-interop)) I changed the code as such:

```
    range = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
    foreach (Excel.Range area in range.Areas)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
            //for (int row = 3; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                Object nObj = ((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[row, "N"]).Text;
            }
    }
```

Except now I'm getting type mismatch errors.  What fundamental thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting a type mismatch at the call to `ws.Cells[row, "N"]`. In the original code, `row` is an `int`. In the modified code, `row` is an `Excel.Range`.

Given that, in the modified code, `row` is a single row (multiple column) range, all you should need to do is index into the cell in that row which corresponds to column N. Assuming your range starts in column A, this will be the cell in 14th column.

E.g.

```
Object nObj = ((Excel.Range)row.Cells[1, 14]).Text;
```

Comment: This response is causing a syntax error for me.  Visual Studio says "No overload for 'this' takes '1' argument."  Cells is looking for two parameters, the rowIndex and ColumnIndex.

Comment: ok, I've edited the answer. Both column index and row index are now being passed.

Comment: That's not correct either.  This is telling nObj to use the value in the literal Cell of [1, 14].

Comment: It's picking the cell in row 1, column 14 of the row object. Note that the code says row.Cells[1, 14] not ws.Cells[1, 14]. In each iteration, the row object is a single row from the current rea object. If the row starts in column A, then column N of the sheet will correspond to the 14th column in the row. If the row does not start in column A then you need to adjust the column index accordingly.

Comment: Yes, a brute force way of doing this would be to add ´if (row.Row == 1) { continue; }´ before the object assignment.

Comment: Sorry, that was a simple question.  However, this method is now running beyond my actual range.  For example, if I only have 254 rows of data, I see this going into row 255.  Is this access all rows now?  Why is this method of access UsedRange giving me more than I expect it to?

Comment: You may have more success taking the first cell and expanding to it's current region. E.g. range = ((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1,1]).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

Comment: Sorry, I'm still at a bit at a loss here.  That doesn't work either.  What is the difference between the two ways I am trying to iterate through the rows?  My first example iterates every row in the range and assigns [row, "N"] a value.  Why is the second not doing that with the caveat that it only be visible after a filter is applied?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the problem posed in your question has been solved? If so, I would propose marking this answer as accepted and opening a separate question regarding any problem you have determining your target range.

Comment: Ok, I get now that the range is now broken up into areas, but what I don't get if why the range seems to extend beyond each range.  I'm noticing the range hits all rows in the correct area as well as areas that have blank rows.  For example, if I only have 254 rows, the codes continues to iterate into the 255th row.  My code currently has to say "(if =='') continue; to prevent blank data from being processed.  That's quite a hack.  I don't understand why the while loop continues beyond the row count....